# How to make postgres (cursor?) start at particular row

Tags: postgresql

I have created the following query:

```
select t.id, t.row_id, t.content, t.location, t.retweet_count, t.favorite_count, t.happened_at,
a.id, a.screen_name, a.name, a.description, a.followers_count, a.friends_count, a.statuses_count,
c.id, c.code, c.name,
t.parent_id
from tweets t
join accounts a on a.id = t.author_id
left outer join countries c on c.id = t.country_id
where t.row_id > %s
-- order by t.row_id
limit 100
```

Where %s is a number that starts at 0 and is incremented by 100 after each such query is conducted. I want to fetch all records from the database using this method, where I just increase the %s in the where condition. I found this approach on https://ivopereira.net/efficient-pagination-dont-use-offset-limit. I also included a column in my table which is corresponding to row number (I named it row_id). Now the problem is when I run this query the first time, it returns rows which have an row_id of 3 million. I would like the cursor (not sure if my terminology is correct) to start from rows with row_id 1 through 100 and so on. The table contains 7 million rows. Am I missing something obvious with which I could achieve my goal?

Comment: If you want an order in a SQL query then you will need to use the `ORDER BY` clause you commented out.  You also should take a look at [LIMIT/OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT)

Comment: You might need to specify the upper bound too (`... AND t.row_id <= %s ...`)?

Comment: Well the whole point of this is to avoid using LIMIT/OFFSET as stated in the article.

Comment: `t.row_id > %s` Are you sure that both operands are text/string types ?